# Ajax.BeginForm onSuccess refreshes Partial View causing events to unbind - anyway to avoid this?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, html-helper

When submitting a form using the `Ajax.BeginForm()` helper in a partial view on MVC4 - `onSuccess` the partial view reloads and and causes all of my events to be unbinded within this partial view. In the following code, on page load the event binded to `.eventButton` would work correctly. Once you attempt to submit the form and receive an error the partial view will refresh and the event binded to `.eventButton` will no longer work.

In my example, it's just one element but in the scenario I'm working with it's a bit more involved. Here's my code with a bit of superfluous information removed.

```
<div id="login">

        @{
            AjaxOptions registerOptions = new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "Post",
                    UpdateTargetId = "login",
                    OnBegin = "showLoading",
                    OnSuccess = "stopLoading"
                };
        }

        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", registerOptions))
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { placeholder = "Your Email" })
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { placeholder = "Your Password" })
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
        }

        <a class="eventButton">Clicking this will trigger an event!</a>

</div>
```

Is there any way for me to submit this form using the MVC4 HTML Helpers via `Ajax.BeginForm()`  without causing the partial view to refresh and also not requiring for me to delegate my events again?

Comment: Can you show your JS. Are you sure you are only referencing jQuery once in solution?

Comment: I just checked and I am completely sure that I have only referenced jQuery once. I'll do my best to get the JavaScript rendered on the page (it's rendered by `Ajax.BeginForm()` and I've initially had some trouble locating it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to tie the event to document.  Change

```
$('.eventButton').on('click', function()...
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.eventButton', function(){...
```

Comment: I believe this is even a tad bit better in terms of performance. Seeing that it requires you to bind less event listeners.